# How to obtain the linear form of Redlich Peterson isotherm model by algebraic transformation or any other ways?

Tags: adsorption

The **Redlich Peterson isotherm model** is known as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
q_e=\frac{AC_e}{1+BC^g_e}
\end{aligned}
$$
Is there any way to obtain the linear form of this equation by algebraic transformation or any ohter ways(like using software origin)?In other words,given that $q_e$ and $C_e$ as variables and A,B,g as parameters,how can I make linear fitting based on this equation?

Comment: What about taking logs on both sides?

Comment: @M. Farooq I am not sure of it.Could you give details?

Comment: a= c/d, log (a)= log (c/d), which is log (a)= log (c)= log (D). Also you can invert the equation 1/qe= 1/AC+ AC/BC^g? Does it make same sense?

Comment: Is this its linear form?

Comment: If you are familiar with Origin (which you suggest) you can fit your data directly. To get initial values for the fitting, for A try the value of q when C is small, and A/B when C is large.

Comment: a= c/d, log (a)= log (c/d), Sorry a typo, log (a)= log (c)- log (D). This is also a linear form 1/qe= 1/AC+ AC/BC^g? If it still does not make sense, watch youtube for linear equations.

Comment: If you want to use a linear form rearrange to  $\displaystyle  \frac{C}{q}=\frac{1}{A}+\frac{B}{A}C^g$ and a plot $C^g$ vs $C/q$ which has intercept $1/a$ and slope $B/A$.

Comment: Directly fitting the equation, as per the first comment by @porphyrin, is the best way to proceed: it does not alter the noise structure and programs like Origin make this curve fitting trivially simple. The linearization idea is from the days before curve fitting software. Personally, I wish it would fade away.